How to use Bowker test or something else for a paired test on nominal data in a non-squared contingency table
Question
According to my research the McNemar test can only be used for 2x2 contingency tables. It's extension, the Bowker test, is applicable for larger contingency tables, but it has to be symmetrical as in 3x3 or 4x4. However, my contingency table is 2x6. Is there a statistical way to perform such analysis anyway? How do I need to create the contingency table from my data to be able to use the Bowker test?

Background
I have the following data frame in R:
df <- structure(list(group = c("pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", 
"pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "pre", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", 
"post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post", "post"), value = c(5, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 
4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 
5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 
3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 
3, 2, 3, NA, 2, 2, 3, NA, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 
3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, NA, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 
3, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1
)), row.names = c(NA, -208L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

These are paired data, indicating a class (column value) before (group == "pre") and after (group == "post") treatment. I would like to compare these paired nominal data. For this I generated a contingency table:
table(df$group, df$value)

Accordingly, using the McNemar or McNemar-Bowker test yields me an error:
mcnemar.test(table(df$group, df$value))

Gives me:
Error in mcnemar.test(table(df\\\$group, df\\\$value)) : 
      'x' must be square with at least two rows and columns


Would it not make more sense to look at the distribution of the pairwise pre/post differences? Something like this, assuming that's how the samples pair up: dtf2 <- as.data.frame(split(df$value, df$group)); table(dtf2$post - dtf2$pre)

What does the "value" variable represent? You say it's a nominal variable, but it consists of integers from 0 to 5, so it looks like it could be an ordinal variable or perhaps a count variable. If you could explain what is the nature of this variable exactly, it would be helpful to give you a correct answer, because there is an ambiguity here.

Thank you for your help. "Value" represents the severity of a condition based on a value obtained through ultrasound. 0=none, 1=trace 2=mild, 3=moderate, 4=severe, 5=torrential. So from my understanding it is an ordinal variable. However, I am primarily looking at the relative frequencies of each value.

In short:

A test might not be necessary, given the data you have.
You've lost the pairing information due to the formatting of your data, which led you down the wrong path (i.e. thinking you cannot get a square contingency table with your data, but you can).
The choice of an adequate test depends on your research question. In general for nominal (non-ordinal) data, an option might be the McNemar-Bowker test, but it could be something else (e.g. the Bhapkar test). If you want to take into account the ordinal nature of your data, a good option could be the Kornbrot rank difference test.
In your specific case, in R, a McNemar-Bowker test won't give you a p-value, due the many zeros in the (correct) contingency table. It brings us back to point 1.

Now, to get into the details:
In comments, you mention that the variable "value" is ordinal, going from "None" (represented by "0") to "Torrential" (represented by "5").
First, just by looking at the data, we may consider that a test is a bit overkill: there is no observation in the "pre" condition with a value below 3 ("moderate"), while almost all observations in the "post" condition are moderate or less. Given your sample size, we may not even need a test to see that there's a difference between the pre and post conditions.
If you still want to conduct a test, I think that where you've gone wrong is with the format you used for your contingency table. Indeed,  you tried to use the following table as an input for the McNemar-Bowker test:




None
Trace
Mild
Moderate
Severe
Torrential




post
9
38
34
16
3
0


pre
0
0
0
43
40
21



You correctly identified the problem: this 2x6 table is not a square and thus cannot be used with a test like the McNemar-Bowker test.
Why is it the case? Because with this table, you lose the pairing information. For instance, try to determine how many observations exactly went from "moderate" to "mild" between the pre and post conditions: this is impossible to tell just from this table. How a test for paired data is supposed to take into account the pairing, if you provide only this table as input?
A more informative table to use for your paired data is this one, that you can use as input of various tests for paired data in R:



post/pre
None
Trace
Mild
Moderate
Severe
Torrential




None
0
0
0
3
5
1


Trace
0
0
0
24
11
3


Mild
0
0
0
11
15
8


Moderate
0
0
0
2
8
6


Severe
0
0
0
1
1
1


Torrential
0
0
0
0
0
0



Some functions in R might also require you the individual vectors of the two groups, rather than a contingency table (e.g. it's the case of the wilcox.test function); still, the order of the two vectors has to match.
How to fix the issue? For a more intuitive and easy-to-use format, you can format your raw data like this (this is assuming that in your original raw data, the order of the two conditions matches):
pre  = factor(df[df$group=="pre",]$value, levels=0:5, ordered=TRUE) 
post = factor(df[df$group=="post",]$value, levels=0:5, ordered=TRUE)
df = data.frame(pre=pre, post=post)




pre
post




5
4


3
2


3
3


...
...



Then you can use that as an input for various functions for paired data in R, including the McNemar-Bowker test. Example in R:
mcnemar.test(x=df$pre, y = df$post)
#Alternatively:
tab = table(df$pre, df$post)
mcnemar.test(tab)

You'll notice that in R, the McNemar-Bowker test will give you p-value = NA, because of the many "0" in your contingency table, where you end up with pairs of symmetric cells both equal to zero. Look at how the McNemar-Bowker statistic is computed: with your data, it implies a division by zero, which is problematic. Other statistical software might handle it differently, but R will return Nan for the p-value, showing there is a problem with the data. There are a few other tests you could use and that won't have this problem (I give some examples a few paragraphs below), but you have to make sure they are appropriate relative to your research question. But again, you may not need a test at all in your scenario.
If you want to take into account the fact your data is ordinal, then a Wilcoxon signed-rank test might be adequate, as mentioned in the other answer, or possibly better the Kornbrot rank difference test (details here and here; an implementation in R of the rank difference test is available here).
Below is an example in R. Note that depending on the test you use, in R you may have to convert the vectors to either a numeric type, or to keep it as a factor type:
wilcox.test(x=as.numeric(df$pre), y=as.numeric(df$post), paired=TRUE)
library(rankdifferencetest)
rdt(data=df, formula=pre~post)

If your research question (that you do not mention in your question) makes the ordinality of the data irrelevant, then besides the McNemar-Bowker test, you have a few other options like the Stuart-Maxwell test or the Bhapkar test. They are both implemented in the DescTools package in R, but there are probably other packages to do that.
The most adequate test to use probably depends on your research question. John Uebersax explains a few options on this page: https://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/mcnemar.htm. Maybe other people will be able to suggest adequate tests, depending on the research question you try to answer.

Why you are using mcnemar.test()? This function is used specifically for 2x2 contingency tables, and it requires the table to be square (i.e., having the same number of rows and columns). Since your contingency table is 2x6, it cannot be analyzed using the McNemar test.
I recommend you to use Chi-squared test. The result will tell you if the distributions across the different categories (pre and post) are significantly different from each other.
In your case it will be result <- chisq.test(tbl)
Result I got on your data:
        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  tbl
X-squared = 0.08, df = 1, p-value = 0.8

which is showing df = 1 and the high p-value no significant. I can tell that the test might not be correctly applied to your 2x6 table.
So you need to create table 2x6
tbl <- table(df$group, df$value)

and if apply Chi-squared test for correct table
tbl
      
        0  1  2  3  4  5
  post  9 38 34 16  3  0
  pre   0  0  0 43 40 21

you will have result as I had
> result

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  tbl
X-squared = 146, df = 5, p-value <2e-16

where X-squared is a large value 146, indicating a significant difference between the observed and expected frequencies.
With  degrees of freedom 5 wich is correct for 2x6 table.
And p-value is extremely small, indicating strong evidence against the null hypothesis. There is a statistically significant difference in the distribution of value between the pre and post groups, and you can report it.
If you want to apply the Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test, you need to ensure the data is paired correctly, so each pre value should be compared to its corresponding post value.
# extract values for pre and post groups
pre_values <- df$value[df$group == "pre"]
post_values <- df$value[df$group == "post"]

# check lengths of pre and post 
if (length(pre_values) != length(post_values)) {
  stop("The number of 'pre' and 'post' values must be equal for paired testing.")
}

# remove NA values to ensure accurate comparison
valid_indices <- complete.cases(pre_values, post_values)
pre_values <- pre_values[valid_indices]
post_values <- post_values[valid_indices]

table(df$group, df$value)

# Perform Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test
result <- wilcox.test(pre_values, post_values, paired = TRUE)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  pre_values and post_values
V = 4742, p-value <2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Here p-value is very small too, which mean difference between the pre and post values is statistically significant.

Data can be transformed to fit McNemar's test: aggregate or summarize your data into meaningful categories.
Also can be consider Wilcoxon Signed-rank test, if value is ordinal or continuous, this test can handle paired differences.

I was rewriting my previous comment, and deleted it. A chi-squared test of independence would be problematic, as the data is paired and violates the assumption of independence of observations. Anyway, I think we should wait for clarification of OP about the nature of the variable before suggesting anything. Solutions may be very different if it's nominal, ordinal, or count data, and I don't think that an answer addressing all possible situations would be very reader-friendly.

As a side note, if the data is ordinal or nominal, I even wonder if it is very informative to conduct a test at all, given the very obvious shift of values between pre and post -it is not really surprising to get a small p-value.

I was thinking of WIlcoxon signed rank test as well. However, I am looking at the relative frequencies.

In this example it is obvious that the p-value would be small. But I have another example where the difference is not so obvious.
